# How to restrict number of windows of window.Open() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

`Codeigniter` page which contents several paragraphs. Each paragraphs clickable and once paragraph is clicked, new window opens with different `url`. User can click any paragraphs even when popup windows are open. Multiple windows are displayed.

I want to make it as if user click a paragraph, only one popup window is open, and if user click another paragraph without closing previous window, close the previous window before open the new new window. Simply one new window at a time.

```js
 $(".target").click(function() {       
   window.open("My URL", "", "width=400, height=300");
 });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <?php 
     foreach ($pro as $data) { 
       echo '<div><p class="target">' . $data->content . '</p></div>';
     } 
   ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the popup window a name, using the second argument to `window.open`. If a window is already open with that name, its contents are replaced.

```
 $(".target").click(function() {       
   window.open("My URL", "mypopup", "width=400, height=300");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to the popup window, and close it when the next one opens. Then you store the new popup in that same variable:

```
var popup = null;
$("p").click(function() {
  if(popup) popup.close()
  popup = window.open("My URL", "", "width=400, height=300");
});
```